# Table centering in latex

Tags: tables

I created a table, but it is a little skewed to the right. Any idea how to fix it? The code is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}

\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Parameters} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model $A$}    &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model $B$}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}

 &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% Bayesian Interval}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% Bayesian Interval}     \\
\midrule



concern &0.006     & (  -0.036, 0.047) & 0.010 & (-0.029,0.050) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest fix is to just add one more row to the header:

[image]

### Notes:

- You should really use math mode for numbers -- This is especially important if they are negative, as the number is not correctly displayed otherwise.  Note how the negative numbers are displayed without math mode:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}

\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Parameters} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model $A$}    &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model $B$}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}

 &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% Bayesian}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% Bayesian}     \\
 &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Interval}     &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Coefficient} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Interval}     \\\midrule

concern &0.006     & $(  -0.036, 0.047)$ & 0.010 & $(-0.029,0.050)$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd also replace `\cmidrule(lr){4-5}` with `\cmidrule(l){4-5}`, i.e., I would *not* trim the rule on the right-hand end.